# Selenium Python Element not found

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, attributes, element

This is a link to HTML I want to **scrape**
https://pk.khaadi.com/unstitched/r20206-red-r20206-red-pk.html

```
<div class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">
      <div class="swatch-option color selected" option-type="1" option- 
       id="61" option-label="RED" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip- 
       value="#ee0000" "="" style="background: #ee0000 no-repeat center; 
       background-size: initial;">
      </div>
      <div class="swatch-option color selected" option-type="1" option- 
       id="73" option-label="YELLOW" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip- 
       value="#feed00" "="" style="background: #feed00 no-repeat center; 
       background-size: initial;">
      </div>
</div>
```

```
Color = S_Driver.find_elements_by_xpath( '//*[@id="product-options-wrapper"]/div/div/div[1]/div' )
```

The Xpath is of the outer div in which both color div are present

```
            for c in Color:
            n_Color.append(c.get_attribute( 'option-label' ))
            print( n_Color + '\n' )
```

This how i tried to extract the color through 'option-label' attribute

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Also, can you share the URL of the page?

Comment: done with the changes you suggested @DebanjanB

Answer (score 0):

Change the xpath with:

```
//div[@class='swatch-option color']
```

Created based on the provided screenshot, hope that there are no other matches on page based on this one. If so, change it with:

```
//div[@class='swatch-option color' and @option-type='1']
```

Comment: its still returns empty list

Comment: I think the data I want to scrap is dynamic as it's not present in the View Page source

Comment: Data as front end elements or xpath is no longer valid?